# backbone router how to hide parameters from url

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am using backbone router to redirect to my pages, I have for example this url

http://localhost:56508/#/RegistryMain/44/1234

The code

```
RegistryMain: function (id, cnt) {
        var self = this;
        this.load();
        require([
         'js/views/Questionaire/RegistryMain'
        ], function (RegistryMainView) {
            self.shell();
            if (typeof app.RegistryMainView !== 'undefined') {
                app.RegistryMainView.destroy();
            }
            app.RegistryMainView = new RegistryMainView({ Id: id, cnt: cnt });
            $("#main-nav li.active").removeClass("active");
            $("#admin").addClass("active");
        });
    },
```

For security reasons, I need to hide `/44/1234` from the url so the user can't reuse them or change them to `/45/1234` for example and access forbidden pages.

How can i do this in backbone?

And if i should use the POST approach, how to use it in backbone?

Comment: You're trying to put your security in the wrong place. People should be able to do whatever they want to the URL (or even the client-side code itself) and still not get access to things they're not authorized to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424654/backbone-router-how-to-hide-parameters-from-url#comment66180788_39424654) is right in saying that you're trying to handle security in the wrong place. You can't trust client-side code, at all.

You should check the rights of the user from the server each time the frontend app calls an API endpoint to avoid your users navigating to pages they don't have the rights to see, or to avoid them messing with the data by posting invalid stuff to an endpoint.

Your API should return a `401 unauthorized` HTTP response code to notify your frontend app of the situation.

And for smooth page transition, redirect the user to an error page if an API call fails.

**That being said**

To avoid showing a url, you can directly call [`loadUrl`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-234):

```
// current url: http://localhost:56508/#/RegistryMain

Backbone.history.loadUrl("RegistryMain/44/1234");

// current url: http://localhost:56508/#/RegistryMain
```

This will trigger the route callback without changing the url, so the user *never* sees the params.

---

> Now that I use `.loadUrl` in my project, all pages have the same URL, but when I refresh a page, it redirects to the *login* page (the first
>   page in my project). **How to make it refresh the current page?**

That's a drawback of not using the url to trigger routes, you now can't know the state of the app as a single page app lives in the current page only and refreshing starts a new instance completely.

You should really rethink if not using the url is the right choice. If it still is, you could save the current url in the localStorage and use it on the app startup to redirect to the right page.

Comment: hi, i use loadUrl but it stopped enter in router code

Comment: @Lili I fixed my answer, you need to remove the leading `#/` from the url.

Comment: i Have one more question, now that i use .loadUrl in my project, all pages have the same URL, when i refresh a page it will redirect me to the log in page(the first page in my projet) how to make it refresh the current page?Note: i tried to use Backbone.history.getFragment() but it's returning nothing. thanks and best regards

Comment: @Lili I added a part to my answer to address this.